# why the code about thread shows a = 1 and b = 3? and why add a "volatile" didn't work?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, volatile

Here is the code:

```
public class ThreadCacheSample {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    public void change() {
        a = 3;
        b = a;
    }

    public void print() {
        if (a == 1 && b == 3) {
            // why this is happening?
            System.out.println("Thread[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]Confused1 : a = 1, b = 3");
        } else if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
            // why this is happening, too?
            System.out.println("Thread[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]Confused2 : a = 3, b = 2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thread[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] b=" + b + ";a=" + a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create many many threads
        while (true) {
            // create test every time, to make sure a is 1 and b is 2 again
            final ThreadCacheSample test = new ThreadCacheSample();

            // one thread for changing
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    test.change();
                }
            }).start();

            // one thread for printing
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    test.print();
                }
            }).start();

        }
    }
}
```

The result should be a = 1, b = 2, or a = 3, b = 3.

My questions are:

1. Why would I get some result that shows "a = 1, b = 3", or"a = 3, b = 2"?
2. If I add "volatile" to a and b, why it didn't work ? 
   I thought volatile will make every thread just access the main memory, instead of their own work memory. So volatile should be a solution. But the reality tells me "volatile" is also not a solution.

   ```
   public class ThreadCacheSample {
       volatile int a = 1;
       volatile int b = 2;
       ...
   }
   ```

p.s. This is **not** a question about how to fix the code. It's about why weird result will appear?

Comment: Your print statements are wrong. They don't represent the condition in `if`. Also, you might want to capture their values in local variables first, then operate on the local variables only.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "Your print statements are wrong. They don't represent the condition in if"?

Comment: They both print `]Confused1 : a = 1, b =     3`.

Comment: great catch. Thank you

Comment: This the obligatory reminder that statements like "*I thought volatile will make every thread just access the main memory, instead of their own work memory.*" describe the behavior of `volatile` in a hypothetical CPU that bears little resemblance to how real CPUs work and in a modern computer, `volatile` does *not* actually force anything to go to main memory. (Which is good. There's lots of inter-core communication on modern CPUs and main memory is *very* slow. It would be a disaster if real CPUs worked this way!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding volatile increases the visibility of the modifications of `a` and `b` individually (as well as adds an ordering dependency between the visibility of their modifications).  it does *not*, however, add any sort of "atomicity" to their *combined* modification.  "volatile" or not, the modification of `a` and the modification of `b` (as well as the reading of `a` and the reading of `b`) are still *independent* actions!

Both of your "confused" answers are possible:

Case 1:

1. init, a == 1, b == 2
2. print thread tests "a == 1"
3. change thread sets "a = 3"
4. change thread sets "a = b" (3)
5. print thread tests "b == 3"
6. confused1

Case 2:

1. init, a == 1, b == 2
2. change thread sets "a = 3"
3. print thread tests "a == 3"
4. print thread tests "b == 2"
5. confused2

Note that *without* volatile, you could get even whackier answers like the print thread seeing "a == 1, b == 3"!

Comment: Does `volatile` make any diference here at all? The way it's coded, both threads have access to effectively the same variables. If anything it may run slower because of `write-through` on every modification.

Comment: @JanezKuhar - i'm not sure what you mean by the "access to the variables", but volatile does rule out one possibility, as i mentioned in my last sentence.  and yes, of course, volatile does have a performance impact.

Comment: You're right, it can't print a=1, b=3 if `volatile` is used, my bad.